# How can I use REGEXP-SUBSTR

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have

```
206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]

205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation -[HASSAN]
```

in one column

How can I use REGEXP to separate them like this in seperate columns:

```
  ACC        Subject       Issue        Name
206579227 |  Account | Account status Enquiry | OLUBUSOLA 
205389263    Loans     Loan Liqidation          HASSAN
```

I tried this i got the number
REGEXP_SUBSTR (regardingobjectname, '(\S*)(\s)') as nuban_number ,

I tried this for the subject also
REGEXP_SUBSTR (regardingobjectname, '(\S*)(\s)(.*)', 1, 3)

Count figure out the others

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: @Vandako . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Im using Oracle  Thank you

Comment: @Vandako, why is it `Account Status` and not `Account Status Enquiry`?

Comment: @Slkrasnodar its Account Status Enquiry

Comment: @Slkrasnodar                                                                                                                  What about a situation when :   203202332 - E-channel - Loan account - [skhddk] 
                                              203202445 - channel - Loan account - [Modupe]

Comment: @Slkrasnodar That was a typo This is the right now: 203202332 - E-channel - Loan account - [HASSAN] 205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation - [DANIEL] 206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with test (col) as (
 select '206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]' from dual union all
 select '205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation - [HASSAN]' from dual union all
 select '205389263 -  - Loan Liqidation - [HASSAN]' from dual union all
 select '205389263 -  -  - [HASSAN]' from dual union all
 select '203202332 - E-channel - Loan account - [skhddk]' from dual union all 
 select '203202445 - channel - Loan account - [Modupe]' from dual
) 
select 
regexp_substr(col, '(.*?) - ', 1, 1, null, 1) acc,
regexp_substr(col, '(.*?) - ', 1, 2, null, 1) subj,
regexp_substr(col, '(.*?) - ', 1, 3, null, 1) issue,
regexp_substr(col, '\[(.+)\]\s*$', 1, 1, null, 1) name
from test
;

ACC                  SUBJ            ISSUE                     NAME           
-------------------- --------------- ------------------------- ---------------
206579227            Account         Account Status Enquiry    OLUBUSOLA      
205389263            Loans           Loan Liqidation           HASSAN         
205389263                            Loan Liqidation           HASSAN         
205389263                                                      HASSAN         
203202332            E-channel       Loan account              skhddk         
203202445            channel         Loan account              Modupe         

6 rows selected.
```

Here the delimiter is [space][dash][space].

for regex explanation:

https://regex101.com/r/ANmLWS/1

https://regex101.com/r/HU6hDr/1/

Comment: What about a situation when :   203202332 - E-channel - Loan account - [skhddk] 
                                              203202445 - channel - Loan account - [Modupe]

Comment: @Vandako, It crossed my mind but you had -[Hassan] which deviated from [space][dash][space] as a delimiter.  If you can guarantee a pattern that is unique then we can look at adjusting the query.

Comment: That was a typo                   This is the right now:                                                                                   203202332 - E-channel - Loan account - [HASSAN]                                   
205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation - [DANIEL]                                      
206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]

Answer (score 0):

As of Oracle, that would be (lines #1 - 4 represent sample data)

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]' from dual union all
  3     select '205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation -[HASSAN]' from dual
  4    )
  5  select t.col,
  6         trim(regexp_substr(t.col, '[^-]+', 1, x.column_value)) val
  7  from test t cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                                             connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '-') + 1
  9                                            ) as sys.odcinumberlist)) x
 10  order by t.col, x.column_value;

COL                                                               VAL
----------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------
205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation -[HASSAN]                     205389263
205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation -[HASSAN]                     Loans
205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation -[HASSAN]                     Loan Liqidation
205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation -[HASSAN]                     [HASSAN]
206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]        206579227
206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]        Account
206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]        Account Status Enquiry
206579227 - Account - Account Status Enquiry - [OLUBUSOLA]        [OLUBUSOLA]

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: COL                                                                                     number                    SUbj
-----------------------------------------------------------------                          -------------------------      --------
205389263 - Loans - Loan Liqidation -[HASSAN]                     205389263               Loan
205389263 - Acc - Loan Liqidation -[HASSAN]                        205389264               Acc

Comment: The answer in the above comment is what i am hoping to get